# Updating ASP.NET repeater data after Postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a repeater that loads a few things into it. I also have a button that has an SQL command to delete all of the contents of the repeater, but unfortunately when the page reloads after the user presses the 'delete' button, the items are still there.

I've tried something like this for the page load sub:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If IsPostBack Then
                bookShelfContainer.DataSource = Nothing
                Exit Sub
            End If
displayUserBooks()
    End Sub
```

And here is the sub for the repeater:

```
 Sub displayUserBooks()
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        Session("currentuser") = User.Identity.Name
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", Session("currentuser"))
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT TOP 6 booklist.ID, booklist.Title, booklist.Author, booklist.imgurl, bookshelfjunction.BookID FROM booklist INNER JOIN bookshelfjunction ON bookshelfjunction.BookID = booklist.ID WHERE bookshelfjunction.UserName = @currentUser")
        bookShelfContainer.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        bookShelfContainer.DataBind()
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

And the delete function just in case you need it:

```
Protected Sub btnClearBookshelf()
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        Session("currentuser") = User.Identity.Name
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", Session("currentuser"))
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("DELETE FROM bookshelfjunction WHERE bookshelfjunction.UserName = @currentUser")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

What do I need to write in the Page_Load If IsPostBack evaluation to make sure that the repeater databinds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing your updates because you are only making them in the database, not in the Repeater control's dataset. It holds on to the DataSet that you bound, and you aren't refreshing it with the new data.

```
Protected Sub btnClearBookshelf()
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Session("currentuser") = User.Identity.Name
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", Session("currentuser"))
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("DELETE FROM bookshelfjunction WHERE bookshelfjunction.UserName = @currentUser")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

    displayUserBooks()

End Sub
```

So, you need to re-get the data to make your app aware of the updates, then bind that new dataset to the Repeater to show the new data. If you thought that would happen because of your events, keep in mind that event handlers run AFTER Page_Load.

Comment: Thank you, very simple in the end ey!

Comment: Yup, pretty simple. BTW, in your Page_load, if it IS a PostBack, you can skip the first call to displayUserBooks() because you know that will be called by the event handler, OR it's a case of a postback that didn't affect your data - those are the two possibilities for a postback. If it's NOT a postback, that's the first time in, always, and you need to initialize everything.

Comment: The example above raises the following error after postback:

    `Invalid attempt to FieldCount when reader is closed`

From the stacktrace I can see that, even If I call the `Repeater.DataBind()` just once, it is actually called twice, and the error arises after the second DataBind call.

Why is this happening? Why the error?

I have read this [question] about doubled DataBind calls (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641156/objectdatasource-firing-twice-or-on-its-own), but it's not my case.